# Survival function of birth-death process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory

There is a linear birth-death process with $N$ states + an absorbing state $0$, with 
$$\Pr[X_{t+1}=0|X_{t}=0]=1, \\
\Pr[X_{t+1}=i+1|X_{t}=i]=\Pr[X_{t+1}=i-1|X_{t}=i]=q_i, i\in [1..N-1],$$
and $X_0=k$. I want to calculate or lower-bound the survival function of this Markov chain $S_t=\Pr[X_t=0]$ with explicit dependence on time $t$. Specifically I am interested in [Moran process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran_process) with $q_i=(N-i)i/N^2$. The generic expression $S_t=\underline{e_k} P^t \overline{1}$, where $P$ is the transition matrix for $N$ states (as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_phase-type_distribution)), does not help, because there is no analytic way to estimate how big $P^t$ is.

Comment: It seems that the probability of jumping from state $i$ to state $i - 1$ is equal to the probability of jumping from state $i$ to state $i + 1$. Hence, both are equal to $1/2$? Is something incorrect in your definition of the transition probabilities?

Comment: Both are equal to q_i, and the probability of staying in the same state i is 1-2q_i